# JSP Encoder Issue While sending Russian character in QueryString

Tags: java, jsp, encoding

I have two jsp pages. I am trying to add "Russian" language. Russian characters are shown perfectly on jsp page, but when I try to send this value to another jsp page from parameter then in second jsp page this value is changed to different characters. This problem is only in Russian Language and not in others such as Italy and French.

For example

```
  On demo.jsp page  the russian character  "приветствие"  is shown correctly. 
 but when I try to send it to another page  "test.jsp"  then some unknown 
 characters are shown like "!C&#60;CÃ¤5 CÃ´&#62;CÃ´CCÂ´OD=CÃ¤5!"
```

Code:
demo.jsp

```
String welcometext=langP.get("welcome");

<jsp:include page="<%=test.jsp%>">
<jsp:param name="wlc" value="<%=Encode.hex8Code(welcometext)%>" />
</jsp:include>
```

In test.jsp

```
String title = Encode.utfToUnicode(Decode.hex8Decode(request.getParameter("wlc")));
System.out.println(" Russial welcome test "+welcome);
```

Is there any special code we need to add for Russia while sending them in query parameters??

Please note* the following code are already written else it would have given problem for French and Italy language too..

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Also tried with following but didn't help out!

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the better solution but the following code solved this issue. I kept the variable in session attribute.

demo.jsp

```
   session.setAttribute("welcometext", welcometext);
```

test.jsp

```
   String welcometest=(String)  session.getAttribute("welcometext");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>` to your main jsp page:

Here is my example:

demo.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Привет</h1>
        <jsp:include page="/test.jsp" flush="true">
            <jsp:param name="wlc" value="Привет"/>
        </jsp:include>  
    </body>
</html>
```

test.jsp

```
<h1>Param values is</h1>
    <%
        String hello = request.getParameter("wlc");
        out.print(hello);
    %>
```

Comment: @Alexey... Nopes .  I tried it placing on my main jsp page and then restarted Tomcat as well.. but same problem!

Comment: @MadanMadan Have you tried to remove all decode and encode methods? Just try my clean example to understand whether it jsp problem or a server problem.